# how to draw a pattern along path in Qt

Tags: qt

Is it possible to draw patterns along path in qt like inkscape: http://math.univ-lille1.fr/~barraud/Inkscape/pathdeform/

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to define your *pattern* within a QPainterPath. Then you can deform the QPainterPath according to your *path*.

See http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/demos-deform.html for a demo of this approach.